# Wagtail : How to set Draftail Editor's text direction to RTL

Tags: wagtail

In wagtail admin RichTextField(), I need to have support for a RTL language. 
I see Draftail it self support this via [textDirectionality](https://www.draftail.org/docs/i18n).

What is the best way to add RTL support in wagtail RichTextField()?

[Here](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.2/advanced_topics/customisation/page_editing_interface.html#limiting-features-in-a-rich-text-field), wagtail docs suggests using `register_rich_text_features` hook to limit features of the editor. But I couldn't find anything about adding textDirectionality to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text directionality will be based on the characters within the editor. So you do not have to do anything. Draftail is Draft.js and the Draft.js documentation says:

> ## textDirectionality?: DraftTextDirectionality
>
> Optionally set the overriding text directionality for this editor. The values include 'RTL' for right-to-left text, like Hebrew or Arabic, and 'LTR' for left-to-right text, like English or Spanish. This directionality will apply to the entire contents, regardless of default text direction for input text.
>
> If this value is not set, text directionality will be based on the characters within the editor, on a per-block basis.

Source: https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-editor.html#textdirectionality

I checked it:

[image: Draftail]

At the moment all options are ignored except features. See Wagtail source code wagtail/admin/rich_text/editors/draftail/__init__.py:20

```
class DraftailRichTextArea(widgets.HiddenInput):
    ...
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # note: this constructor will receive an 'options' kwarg taken from the WAGTAILADMIN_RICH_TEXT_EDITORS setting,
        # but we don't currently recognise any options from there (other than 'features', which is passed here as a separate kwarg)
        kwargs.pop('options', None)
        self.options = {}
```

If you require more control, you can always override the widget template. See [wagtail/admin/templates/wagtailadmin/widgets/draftail_rich_text_area.html](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/master/wagtail/admin/templates/wagtailadmin/widgets/draftail_rich_text_area.html)

Comment: You are right. It detects it automatically. I applied dir=rtl to other inputs in admin interface, but couldn't figure out how to do the same for wysiwyg editor. Never tried putting actual RTL text there. Silly me! Thank you very much.